# Launching activity's Intent extra is not updated

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 apps in the same device. One in unity3D and other in android studio. My unity code is not getting updated intent extras instead it gets the intent extras of the intent which initially launched the app. If the unity app has been running on background the intent extra in unity never get updated.

I want to get the updated intent.extra from android app to unity app. How can I do it?

android studio code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void sendMessage(View view) {
      getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.amali.UnityApp").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.amali.UnityApp");
        if (launchIntent != null) {

            launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            String s = "hello " + incrementedstring;   //updating the string passing to unity app
            launchIntent.putExtra("arguments", s);
            Bundle extras= launchIntent.getExtras();
            Log.d(TAG, extras.getString("arguments"));  //this prints correctly
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
```

}

unity code:

```
void GetAndroidAppArguments()
{
    string arguments = "";
    try
    {
        AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
        bool hasExtra = intent.Call<bool>("hasExtra", "arguments");
        if (hasExtra)
        {
            AndroidJavaObject extras = intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getExtras");
            arguments = extras.Call<string>("getString", "arguments");
            debugLog.text = arguments;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        debugLog.text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

It seems like intent's extras never get updated. I am struggling with this for weeks. Please help me.

Comment: Why should onNewIntent() be called? What has it to do with starting an activity? And what is 'updating an intent,'?

Comment: And what do you mean with 'the intent which initially launched the app'? Which app?

Comment: `public void sendMessage()` public? Why public?

Comment: What should setIntent() ,do?

Comment: 1. I am sorry for the unclear statement. I want to update value of the intent extra named "arguments".

Comment: 2. unity app is being launched by the android app. So app= unity app

Comment: Why would you? Where? You give it a a value once. Then start the activity. Why should the value of 'arguments' be changed? Why? By whom? For what?

Comment: Please start answering my first question. Then answer all questions.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I want to pass a message to the unity app from android app.

Comment: onNewIntent() is just to check whether I am creating a new intent when I am calling "getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.amali.UnityApp");"  just for testing purposes.

Comment: What would you test? And it is never called! And has nothing to do with you starting a unity app. So what is it that you are after?

Comment: `want to get the updated intent.extra `. It is still unclear to me which intent you consider to be 'updated'. Whatever that would be. I see only one intent. You called it launchIntent.

Comment: Okay. Sorry again for the confusion. I editted it. Let me demonstrate it, I open the android app and call sendMessage() method. Then it will start the lauching activity of unity with argument="hello". Using the unity app I come back to the android app. Then again I call sendMessage() method. Now argument="hellohello" and launching the unity app. Still unity shows argument="hello"

Comment: And when and where do you call getAndroidAppArguments()? And is the unity app not closed 'if you come back to android app'?

Comment: What is 'incrementedstring'? How should that work? Are you shure you send hellohello? Display a toast with the string while launching the activity.

Comment: Instead of a unity app take another app which you made with AS. Post the code with which you try to get the intent values. I know nothing of unity and cannot check that code.

Comment: Its in a script that attached to a gameobject. OnUpdate() triggers the method. Even the app is running on the background before the unity launch activity is called, the method will be called. :)

Comment: But when is it called? There should be an event that you use. You should implement onNewIntent() in that unity app.

Comment: Are you shure you send hellohello? -> yes,  Log.d(TAG, extras.getString("arguments")); this prints hellohello

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer well the Android App because we used Cordova with a Plugin to send the extras (a var called *varName*). But we had got problems in the Unity app. In our case this works perfectly:

```
AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 

 AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

 AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");

 String text = intent.Call<String> ("getStringExtra", "varName");
```

The thing was that we tried your code, but we didn't get anything. After a while, we notice that *Call* calls a Java method, so we try the *getStringExtra* method to get the specific value.

Cheers.